# Strange sqlalchemy error with '|' operator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm creating a query with sqlalchemy and I don't know why i get this error. Basicaly my code looks like this :

```
def post(self, semestr):
    nazwa_kierunku = 'stac. I st., kier. informatyka'
    nr_semestru = 2

    nr_grupy_cw = 3
    nr_grupy_ps = 5
    nr_grupy_l = 7
    nr_grupy_w = 1
    nr_grupy_p = 2
    nr_grupy_s = 5
    nr_grupy_j = 5
    nr_grupy_wf = 1

    prowadzacy_tytul_subq = model.Prowadzacy.query.join(model.Tytul).subquery()

    query = (
        model.Grupa.query.join(prowadzacy_tytul_subq,
                               model.Studia,
                               model.Przedmiot,
                               model.Sala)
            .filter(model.Studia.nazwa == nazwa_kierunku)
            .filter(model.Grupa.nr_semestru == nr_semestru)
            .filter((model.Grupa.rodzaj == 'Ćw', model.Grupa.nr_grupy == nr_grupy_cw) | (model.Grupa.rodzaj == 'Ps' , model.Grupa.nr_grupy == nr_grupy_ps))


    )
    print(query)
    result = schema.GrupaSchema().dump(query, many=True)

    return jsonify(result)
```

When I mouse over the '|' operator i get "Class'(bool,bool)' does not define '**or**', so the '|' operator cannot be used on its instances"

During compilation I get 
"sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type  instead" What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `or` instead?

Comment: When i use 'or' the error i get is:
"sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type <class 'tuple'> instead"

Comment: `or` expects a boolean value in both sides. You are doing `(bool, bool) or (bool, bool)`. Try changing it for `(bool and bool) or (bool and bool)`

Comment: Ok, the code starts compiling after  that change, but I print this query and I can see that in this query there is nothing from last filter, just like this line doesn't exist
"WHERE studia.nazwa = %(nazwa_1)s AND grupa.nr_semestru = %(nr_semestru_1)s AND grupa.rodzaj = %(rodzaj_1)s" That's how query is ending.

Answer (score 1):

In `sqlalchemy` library, you should use the `or_()` with the conditions as the arguments.

and validate that `condition_1` and `condition_2` are `bool` objects. and not `class(bool, bool)` as you mentioned.

For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_
select().where( or_(condition_1, condition_2) )
```